# Android, why is this Button staying as null when assigning its value based off findViewById

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am assigning the value of a Button variable, to one of the button's created in my XML layout, i have given the button in the XML a suitable id, and i refer to this when assigning the value to the Button which remains null.

The problem occurs in this method:

```
public void addListenerOnButtons() {


        updateInfoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updateWalkInfoButton);

        updateInfoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
                resultIntent.putExtra("newName", "");
                resultIntent.putExtra("newSDesc", "");
                resultIntent.putExtra("newLDesc", "");
                setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
                finish();

            }

        });


    helpButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.helpButton);

    helpButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, HelpScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

updateInfoButton remains null after this method, which causes my app to crash, the XML for this page is as follows:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/createScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".EditWalksInfoActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/formLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/editWalkInfoHeaderTextView"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/editWalkInfoHeaderText"
            android:textColor="@color/light_gray" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editWalkNameEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editWalkTitleTextView"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:ems="6"
            android:hint="@string/createWalkNameHint"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColor="@color/light_gray" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editWalkShortDescEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editWalkShortDescTextView"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:ems="6"
            android:hint="@string/createWalkShortDescHint"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColor="@color/light_gray" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editWalkLongDescEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editWalkLongDescTextView"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:ems="6"
            android:hint="@string/createWalkLongDescHint"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:textColor="@color/light_gray" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/updateWalkInfoButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editWalkLongDescEditText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/updateWalkInfoButtonText"
            android:textColor="@color/light_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/editWalkShortDescTextView"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editWalkNameEditText"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/createWalkShortDescTextView"
            android:textColor="@color/light_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/editWalkTitleTextView"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editWalkShortDescTextView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editWalkInfoHeaderTextView"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/createWalkTitleTextView"
            android:textColor="@color/light_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/editWalkLongDescTextView"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editWalkShortDescTextView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editWalkShortDescEditText"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/createWalkLongDescTextView"
            android:textColor="@color/light_gray" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/editWalkHelpButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editWalkTitleTextView"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editWalkInfoHeaderTextView"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:contentDescription="@string/helpIconAltText"
            android:src="@drawable/help" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxxxxx"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <permission
        android:name="xxxxxx".MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <!-- Accessing camera hardware -->
    <!-- putting android.hardware.camera prevents non-camera devices using this app -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="xxxxxx".MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps"
            android:required="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="xxxxxx.StartScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="xxxxxx.CreateWalkActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create_walk"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="xxxxxx.HelpScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_help_screen"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="xxxxxx.WalkRecording"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_walk_recording"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="xxxxxx.CreateNewPOIActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create_new_poi"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBriHozWKei0lNm0XP2SR3hz8GW790L1eA" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="xxxxxx.ConfrimUploadActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_confrim_upload"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="xxxxxx.ServerResponse"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_server_response"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="xxxxxx.EditWalksInfoActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_walks_info" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the logcat output:

```
01-06 19:09:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(6958): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 19:09:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(6958): Process: dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02, PID: 6958
01-06 19:09:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(6958): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02/dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.EditWalksInfoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-06 19:09:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(6958):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
01-06 19:09:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(6958):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
01-06 19:09:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(6958):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-06 19:09:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(6958):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
01-06 19:09:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(6958):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-06 19:09:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(6958):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-06 19:09:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(6958):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-06 19:09:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(6958):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 19:09:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(6958):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-06 19:09:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(6958):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-06 19:09:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(6958):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-06 19:09:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(6958):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-06 19:09:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(6958): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-06 19:09:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(6958):     at dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.EditWalksInfoActivity.addListenerOnButtons(EditWalksInfoActivity.java:78)
01-06 19:09:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(6958):     at dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.EditWalksInfoActivity.onCreate(EditWalksInfoActivity.java:30)
01-06 19:09:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(6958):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
01-06 19:09:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(6958):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-06 19:09:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(6958):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
01-06 19:09:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(6958):     ... 11 more
```

EDIT:

order method is called:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_walks_info);
        context = this;
        locateUIElements();
        addListenerOnButtons();
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra("Walk info");
        if (bundle != null){

            name = bundle.getString("walkTitle");
            sDesc = bundle.getString("walkSDesc");
            lDesc = bundle.getString("walkLDesc");
            setEditTextValues();

        }

    }
```

Comment: That is weird, I see nothing wrong, maybe you forgot to call `setContentView`?

Comment: @RohanKandwal this is line 78: helpButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

Comment: This means that the actual problem is with helpButton, not updateInfoButton. Please provide part of addListenerOnButtons method where you initialize and use helpButton (line 78 +-5 lines).

Comment: @solmaks added code to post, but the help button functions fine within the application.

Comment: None of the widgets in the provided XML layout have R.id.helpButton assigned as their id. This is why (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.helpButton); returns null and you get NPE.

Comment: i updated this to reflect the XML so it now reads editWalkHelpButton as the R.id for the helpButton, this does not help my problem which is the fact that the updateInfoButton is null, i checked in the de bugger

Answer (score 4):

The problem in your question is that there's no `id/helpButton` in your XML.

```
helpButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.helpButton);
```

but

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/editWalkHelpButton"
```

The `R.id.helpButton` probably is from some other resource file so it's a valid identifier.

The follow-up problem you're seeing is because the identifiers in generated `R.java` and binary XML files are out of sync. This is a common problem when editing layout XML files and reordering elements with `@+id` identifiers. The solution is to clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: i updated this to reflect the XML so it now reads editWalkHelpButton as the R.id for the helpButton, this does not help my problem which is the fact that the updateInfoButton is null, i checked in the de bugger

Comment: If you've recently edited the layout XML, clean and rebuild just in case. It's a common problem that resource ids in R.java and binary XML files are out of sync, giving you all kinds of problems.

Comment: wow, seriously! is that all it took! thanks a lot! it has been doing my head in for a while!

Answer (score 2):

You are probably trying to get your button prior to activity view hierarchy being inflated. Call your addListenerOnButtons method after Activity.setContentView.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // call sequence is important
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    addListenerOnButtons();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is one potential disaster, here:

> updateInfoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updateWalkInfoButton);

Chances that by the time that code gets executed the View is not ready yet are extremely high, and keeps a null reference, make sure to move that code somewhere after setContentView is executed, maybe in the onCreate right after setContentView or somewhere after view is set...

Regards!

Comment: added code to my post, it is in fact called in the correct order. thanks.

Comment: what happens if you move the "addListenerOnButtons" method to "onStart"?

Comment: the same problem occurs.

Comment: Ok, I don't know what android version you are using but try this: RelativeLayout form = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.formLayout), and from form try to find your button...

Answer (score 0):

Is the wrong context being set? Is `activity_edit_walks_info` the name of the ScrollView Layout XML you posted? Because the context defined in the XML is `EditWalksInfoActivity`.

Also, is `updateInfoButton` in addListenerOnButtons() set globally? If so, can you post where that is defined?

Comment: the button updateInfoButton is defined as a private member of the Class containing the addListenerOnButtons() method, it is defined as private Button updateInfoButton;

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was to simply clean the project:

in eclipse go to:

project>clean and it seems to fix a lot of the problems you may have in regards to the application being out of sync with its resources.

Special thanks to user : laalto for the suggestion.